# How to remove glossy reflections from enviroment texture on the floor only

Tags: reflection

I am using Blender 2.90.1 and I can’t find any simple tutorial how to remove glossy reflections from enviroment texture just from one object. Is it possible make that, without rendering more layers and mask them in the end?

(How to remove reflection from enviromental texture marked as red on the screenshot)
[image]

Comment: Enabling the render layers doesn't cost you anything while rendering, it just exposes them as outputs in the compositor.  FYI :)